# Owl Carousel - return to default transitionStyle

Tags: carousel, owl-carousel

I have an Owl Carousel question that I couldn't find any answer to.

Once I change the transitionStyle,
like: `owl.data('owlCarousel').reinit({transitionStyle:'backSlide'});`

How can I return it to the default (right to left) slider ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could find the answer only after digging into "owl.carousel.js".
Here it is:
owl.data('owlCarousel').reinit({transitionStyle:**false**});